# RGB Color Game if block sometime work and sometime won't work

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom, dom-events

Hey I am try to create a RGB Color game, here I am facing a Issue that when I refers the tab then inside my randomDiv() function there is a If block(color_fix) which is sometime working and sometime won't working you can check through clicking on refresh tab button inside console, please solve this problem

```js
let first_div = document.getElementById('first_div');
let h4 = document.querySelector('h4');
let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
let color_div = document.querySelector('#color_div');
let createDiv;

h4.style.alignItems = 'center';
h4.append(h1);
let valueRGB = rgb();
h1.innerText = valueRGB.toUpperCase();
h1.style.alignItems = 'center';
first_div.style.backgroundColor = rgb();

function rgb() {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 0);
  let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 0);
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 0);
  return (`rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`);
}

function threeRandomNumber() {
  let threeRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
  return threeRandomNumber;
}

function divCreate() {
  createDiv = document.createElement('div');
  createDiv.classList = 'dynamacily_create_div';
  createDiv.style.backgroundColor = `${rgb()}`;
  return createDiv;
}

function randomDiv() {
  let color_fix = threeRandomNumber();
  console.log('outter Background ' + color_fix);
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let div_fix = threeRandomNumber();
    if (div_fix === 1) {
      color_div.appendChild(divCreate());
      console.log('outter Background inner' + color_fix);
      if (color_fix === 1) {
        createDiv.style.backgroundColor = valueRGB;
        console.log(valueRGB);
        console.log('inner Background ' + color_fix);
      }
    } else if (div_fix === 2) {
      color_div.appendChild(divCreate());
      console.log('outter Background inner' + color_fix);
      if (color_fix === 2) {
        createDiv.style.backgroundColor = valueRGB;
        console.log(valueRGB);
        console.log('inner Background ' + color_fix);
      }
    } else {
      color_div.appendChild(divCreate());
      console.log('outter Background inner' + color_fix);
      if (color_fix === 3) {
        createDiv.style.backgroundColor = valueRGB;
        console.log(valueRGB);
        console.log('inner Background ' + color_fix);
      }
    }
  }

}
randomDiv()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

h4,
h5 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#first_div {
  width: 900px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#color_div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dynamacily_create_div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div id="first_div">
      <h4>THE GREAT</h4>
      <h5>GUESSING GAME</h5>
    </div>
    <div id="second_div">
      <button id="newColor">New Color</button>
      <button id="playAgain">Play Again</button>
      <button id="tryAgain">Try Again</button>
      <button id="correct">Correct</button>
      <button id="easy">Easy</button>
    </div>
    <div id="color_div">

    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some logical branches are ignored by you.

Both **div_fix** and **color_fix** are returned by threeRandomNumber().

**div_fix** can be any one of [1,2,3].

**color_fix** can be any one of [1,2,3]. They can be the same or not.

While div_fix===1 and color_fix===2 , code is missing.

While div_fix===1 and color_fix===3 , code is missing.

Please check and fix your problem.

```
if (div_fix === 1) {
  color_div.appendChild(divCreate());
  console.log('outter Background inner' + color_fix);
  if (color_fix === 1) {
    createDiv.style.backgroundColor = valueRGB;
    console.log(valueRGB);
    console.log('inner Background ' + color_fix);
  }else{
    // Here!! maybe color_fix === 2 or color_fix === 3, Do sth.
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this solves OP's  issue then?

Comment: @aryan raj If helps, please comment.

Comment: Please write a coherent answer. English may not be your primary language, but this answer is incomprehensible.